# Merging matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have 100 matrices with the same number of rows and columns. I want to merge them all in one matrix.  What is the best way to do that?

I have already tried "append", but I do not know why the result matrix is empty. Here is what I have done:

```
    Aggregate<-function(files,filepath,Matrix){
             for(f in files) {
                file<-file.path(filePath,f)
                temp<-read.table(file,head=T)
                for( i in 1:nrow(temp)){
                    append(Matrix,temp[i, ])
                }
             }
    return(Matrix)
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with this code?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *merge*?

Comment: `append` appends values to vectors not to matrices.  You should use `rbind` or `cbind`.

Comment: I want to aggregate all of them in one big matrix. The size of very matrix is 240x85

Comment: What are the dimensions of the original matrix?

Comment: The size of very matrix is 240x85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [cbind or rbind](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/cbind.html)

> Take a sequence of vector, matrix or data frames arguments and combine
>   by columns or rows, respectively. These are generic functions with
>   methods for other R classes.

Comment: A more complete answer would be to collect all the matrices into a list first `lapply`-ing `read.table` over the filenames/paths and then call `do.call(rbind, listofmatrices)`

Comment: How can I collect all the matrices into a list? I'm using file.path to  access desired matrices in a specific path. Should I use do.call for file.path as well?